# XRegexP.matchRecursive - add callback functionality to allow for multiple identical instances

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I am using XRegexP to parse a text file specifically to find the contents between two sets of pre-defined comment tags, I'm not able to change these tags so I need to find a way to make it work with the text provided.

I find a list of all of the tags using the regex provided (example in link also includes sample content): https://regex101.com/r/kCwyok/1/

I've then used XRegexP's `matchRecursive` function to get all the content in between the opening and closing tags which all works - almost - perfectly.

```
// Map the list of component tags and extract data from them
return generateComponentList(data).map((component) => {
    console.log(chalk.blue('Processing', component[1], 'component.'))
    const contents = XRegExp.matchRecursive(data, '<!-- @\\[' + component[1] + '\\][.\\w-_+]* -->', '<!-- @\\[/' + component[1] + '\\] -->', 'g')
    let body = ''
    let classes = ''

    contents.map((content) => {
      const filteredContent = filterContent(content)
      body = filteredContent.value
      classes = cleanClasses(component[2])
      console.log(chalk.green(component[1], 'processing complete.'))
    })

    // Output the content as a JSON object
    return {
      componentName: component[1],
      classes,
      body
    }
  })
```

The problem I have is that the `CodeExample` tag exists twice, the tag is identical but the content is different, however, because `matchRecursive` doesn't appear to have a callback function, it just runs the match on all instances of that component at the same time so it doesn't matter if there are 1 or 10 instances of `CodeExample` the content for all of them is returned.

Is there a way I CAN actually add some sort of callback to matchRecursive? Failing that is there a way I can make JavaScript understand which instance of CodeExample is being looked at so I can just reference the array position directly? I presume XRegexP has an idea of which number CodeExample tag it's looking at, so is there a way to capture it?

Here is the full code for sake of clarity: https://pastebin.com/2MpdvdNA

The desired output I want is a JSON file with the following data:

````
[
{
 componentName: "hero",
 classes: "",
 body: "# Creating new contexts"
},
{
 componentName: "CodeExample",
 classes: "",
 body: "## Usage example

    ```javascript
      Import { ICON_NAME } from 'Icons'
    ```"
},
{
 componentName: "ArticleSection",
 classes: "",
 body: // This section is massive and not relevant to question so skipping
},
{
 componentName: "NoteBlock",
 classes: ["warning"],
 body: "> #### Be Careful
> Eu laboris eiusmod ut exercitation minim laboris ipsum magna consectetur est [commodo](/nope)."
},
{
 componentName: "CodeExample",
 classes: "",
 body: "#### Code example
```javascript
  class ScrollingList extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.listRef = React.createRef();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          &#60;div ref={this.listRef}&#62;{/* ...contents... */}&#60;/div&#62;
        );
      }
    }
```"
}
// Skipping the rest as not relevant to question
]
````

Sorry if I've not explained this clearly, I've been looking at this for far too long.

Comment: There are a lot of variables and functions in the code that haven't been defined or explained. Assuming that the text in the regex101 is your input (as well as the tag names in `component`), can you post your desired output?

Comment: I've updated the question with some extra details, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it was resolved in the end:

```
import XRegExp from 'xregexp'

const extractComponents = data => {
  const components = []
  const re = '<!-- @\\[(\\w+)\\]([.\\w-_+]+)* -->'

  XRegExp.forEach(data, XRegExp(re, 'g'), match => {
    const name = match[1]
    const classes = match[2]

    const count = components.filter(item => item.name === name).length
    const instance = count ? count : 0

    components.push({
      name,
      classes,
      instance
    })
  })

  return components
}

const cleanClasses = classes => {
  const filteredClasses = classes ? classes.split('.') : []
  filteredClasses.shift()

  return filteredClasses
}

const extractContent = (data, component) => {
  const re = `<!-- @\\[${component.name}\\][.\\w-_+]* -->`
  const re2 = `<!-- @\\[/${component.name}\\] -->`

  return XRegExp.matchRecursive(
    data, 
    re, re2, 'g'
  )[component.instance]
}

const parseComponents = data => {
  return extractComponents(data).map(component => {
    return {
      componentName: component.name,
      classes: cleanClasses(component.classes),
      body: extractContent(data, component)
    }
  })
}

export default parseComponents
```